# Query in Spring repository

Tags: spring, hibernate

My SQL is

```
SELECT formid 
  FROM (SELECT formid, COUNT(*) cc FROM formevalremarks
                 WHERE completed='Y' GROUP BY formid)
 WHERE (formid, cc) IN
                (SELECT formid, COUNT(*) dd FROM formevalremarks GROUP BY formid)
```

how to write it in `@Query` in Spring Repo????

---

I tried ..

`@Query("select f.formId  from 
                           (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*)  f.cc  FROM FormEvalRemarks                                f WHERE f.completed='Y' GROUP BY f.formId) 
                        where (f.formId ,f.cc ) 
                           in (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*) f.dd  FROM                       FormEvalRemarks f GROUP BY f.formId)")

   List<Long> complForms()`;

its getting... `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException`

Comment: you can use native query in `@Query(custome SQL)` by enabling `nativeQuery = true` but will loose database independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have that exception in the morning, the correct way to do that is.

```
@Query("select f.formId as formID  from 
         (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*)  f.cc  FROM FormEvalRemarks f WHERE f.completed='Y' GROUP BY f.formId) where (f.formId ,f.cc )  in (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*) f.dd  FROM FormEvalRemarks f GROUP BY f.formId)" , native=true)
   List<Long> methodToExecute();
```

If that does not work try using.

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="MyQuery", query="select f.formId as formID  from (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*)  f.cc  FROM FormEvalRemarks f WHERE f.completed='Y' GROUP BY f.formId) where (f.formId ,f.cc )  in (SELECT f.formId ,COUNT(*) f.dd  FROM FormEvalRemarks f GROUP BY f.formId)", resultSetMapping = "MyMapper")

@SqlResultSetMapping(name="MyMapper",
    columns={
        @ColumnResult(name="formID")
    }
)

@Query(name="MyQuery" , native=true)
List<Object> methodToExecute();
```